# When are subviews completely, correctly laid out?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I am trying to programmatically draw a circle progress view and center it within a subview `circleView`, which I have set up/constrained in the interface builder.  However, I am not sure when `circleView`'s final size and center will be accessible (I'm using auto layout), which I ultimately need to draw the circle.  Here's the involved code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!

let circleShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // createCircle()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    print(circleView.frame.size.width)
    createCircle()
}

func createCircle() {

    // Draw/modify circle

    let center = circleView.center

    // Where I need to use circleView's width/center
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: circleView.frame.size.width, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    circleView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    circleShapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    circleShapeLayer.strokeColor = Colors.tintColor.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    circleShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    // circleShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

    circleView.layer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)

}
```

This prints the width of `circleView` twice, and only on the second run of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is it actually correct:

```
207.0
187.5 // Correct (width of entire view is 375)
```

However, the circle draws incorrectly along the same exact path both times, which baffles me because the width changes as shown above.  Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way?

I'd rather not draw the circle twice and was hoping there would a way to run `createCircle()` within `viewDidLoad()` instead, but at the moment this just gives me the same result.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: note **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is called multiple times

Comment: You would be better off writing a custom `UIView` subclass that implements the circle view instead of putting all of that code in your view controller.

Comment: that initial size of 207 is probably based on storyboard setting, defaulting to a 414 width screen, and then when it gets actually laid out, it resizes to your device, 375 width screen.    viewWillAppear should have your circle at the right size.  it sounds like auto constraints may be what you need to look into.  This may be helpful.  https://marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@rmaddy's comment is correct: The best way to handle this is to use a custom view to manage `trackLayer` and `circleShapeLayer`. Override the custom view's `layoutSubviews` to set the frame and/or path of the layers.

That said, I'll answer your stated question of “When are subviews completely, correctly laid out?”

Consider this view hierarchy:

```
A
|
+--- B
|    |
|    +--- C
|    |
|    +--- D
|
+--- E
     |
     +--- F
     |
     +--- G
```

During the layout phase of the run loop, Core Animation traverses the layer hierarchy in depth-first order, looking for layers that need layout. So Core Animation visits A's layer first, then B's layer, then C's layer, then D's layer, then E's layer, then F's layer, then G's layer.

If a layer needs layout (its `needsLayout` property is true), then Core Animation sends `layoutSublayers` to the layer. A layer handles this by default by sending `layoutSublayersOfLayer:` to its delegate. Usually the delegate is the `UIView` that owns the layer.

By default, a `UIView` handles `layoutSublayersOfLayer:` by (among other things) sending three messages:

1. The `UIView` sends `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to its view controller, if the view is owned by a view controller.
2. The `UIView` sends itself `layoutSubviews`.
3. The `UIView` sends `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to its view controller, if the view is owned by a view controller.

In the default implementation of `-[UIView layoutSubviews]`, the view sets the frame of each of its direct subviews, based on auto layout constraints.

Note that in `layoutSubviews`, a view only sets the frames of its **direct** subviews. So for example, A only sets the frames of B and E. It does **not** set the frames of C, D, F, and G.

So let's suppose A is the view of a view controller, but none of the other views are owned by a view controller.

When A's handles `layoutSubviews`, it sets the frames of B and E. Then it sends `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to its view controller. The frames of C, D, F, and G have **not** been updated at this point. The view controller cannot assume that C, D, F, and G have correct frames in its `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

There are two good places to put code that will run when C's frame has definitely been updated:

1. Override B's `layoutSubviews`. Since B is the direct superview of C, you can be sure that after B's `layoutSubviews` calls `super.layoutSubviews()`, C's frame has been updated.
2. Put a view controller in charge of B. That is, make B be the view of some view controller. Then, override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in the view controller that owns B.

If you only need to know when C's size has definitely been updated, you have a third option:

3. Override C's `layoutSubviews`. This will be called if `C` changes size. It won't necessarily be called if C changes position but stays the same size.

Comment: Rob, Are you on Codementor or any other site?

Comment: I am not on Codementor or any other site where you can pay me for help.

Comment: Well done, Rob.

Comment: There needs to be an extension that bubbles things all the way back up to the parent and handles all the counting inbetween will/didLayoutSubviews and then calls some other method, didLayoutSubviewsCompletely... :)

Answer (score 0):

Like others before, you should write the circle view as a standalone object .  Just subclass UIView and call it each time you need it.

I took your  code and got started:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyCircle : UIView {

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        setupViews();
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    func setupViews() {
        let circleShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        // Draw/modify circle
        let center = self.center

        // Where I need to use circleView's width/center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: self.frame.size.width, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        circleShapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        circleShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circleShapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        circleShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleShapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        circleShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

}
```

I just threw some rando colors but I think you get the point...

Comment: Why hardcode a size in `init()`? Just override `init(frame:)`. And this code doesn't handle the view's size changing at all. It would actually be easier to override `draw` instead of bothering with layers that need to be updated.

Comment: yep..I agree..trying to bridge the gap between what op wrote and where they can go.