# layoutSubviews vs frame didSet to detect when the view's frame changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Say I have a UIView subclass that needs to update something when its frame changes. E.g. when it's on an even pixel, it'll be red, and blue when it's on an odd pixel.

I've seen at least four ways to do this:

1. [`view.layoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews):

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       backgroundColor = calculateColorFromFrame(frame)
   }
   ```
2. [`view.frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) `didSet`:

   ```
   override var frame: CGRect {
       didSet {
           backgroundColor = calculateColorFromFrame(frame)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a KVO observer on the view's frame.
4. On the view's wrapping UIViewController, implement [`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews).

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       view.updateBackgroundColorForNewFrame()
   }
   ```
5. Any other way you know of?

Which of these methods is preferred, and is one inherently better than the other? What's Apple's official recommendation?

Answer (score 19):

1. `layoutSubviews`: You can rely on this being called on a view whose size has changed, or if the view has received `setNeedsLayout`. If the view's position changes but its size doesn't change, the system doesn't automatically call `layoutSubviews` on that view.
2. `frame didSet`: This works for a view that is laid out using `autoresizingMask`. It does not work for a view laid out using normal constraints. Instead, auto layout sets the view's `center` and `bounds`. However, these are implementation details subject to change in different versions of UIKit. I tested on the iOS 12.0 Simulator that comes with Xcode 10 beta 6.
3. KVO on `frame`: This won't work in some circumstances for the same reason as #2. Also, `frame` is not documented to be KVO-compliant, so UIKit is allowed to change `frame` without notifying observers.
4. `viewDidLayoutSubviews`: This can only work if the view is the `view` property of the view controller, and then only if the `view` receives the `layoutSubviews` message (see #1). Also it's important to understand that when this is called, the view controller's `view` and its direct subviews have been laid out, but deeper subviews have **not** been laid out yet. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254623/77567) for a fuller explanation.)

Note also that a view's `frame` is computed from some properties of its `layer`: the layer's `position`, `bounds.size`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform`. If anything sets those layer properties directly, none of the above methods will work.

Because of all this, there's no particularly *great* way to be notified when the view's position changes. The technically correct way is probably to use a `CAAction`. When the layer detects that its `position` is changing, it asks its delegate (which is the view itself, for a view's layer) for an action to run. It asks by sending the `actionForLayer:forKey:` message. So you can override `action(forLayer:forKey:)` in your view subclass to be notified reliably. However, the layer asks for the action **before** changing its `position` (and hence its `frame`). It runs the action **after** changing its `position`. So you have to go through a little dance like this:

```
override func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
    class MyAction: CAAction {
        init(view: MyView, nextAction: CAAction?) {
            self.view = view
            self.nextAction = nextAction
        }
        let view: MyView
        let nextAction: CAAction?
        func run(forKey event: String, object: Any, arguments: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {


            // THIS IS WHERE YOU LOOK AT THE NEW FRAME AND ACT ACCORDINGLY.


            print("This is the action. Frame now: \(view.frame)")
            nextAction?.run(forKey: event, object: object, arguments: arguments)
        }
    }

    let action = super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
    if event == "position" {
        return MyAction(view: self, nextAction: action)
    } else {
        return action
    }
}
```

The `UIView` implementation of `actionForLayer:forKey:` normally returns `nil`. But inside an animation block (including when the interface is rotating between portrait and landscape), it returns (for some keys) an action that installs a `CAAnimation` on the layer. So it's important to run the action returned by `super` if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Since frame encapsulates both position and size, I'd be interested to know how to handle size changes correctly too. Would I just use the same CAAction trick and look for an event similar to `position`? If so, what which event name should I look for? I tried looking up values in the documentation, and the best I could find are either `frame` or `bounds`. However, it seems if I would use either one of these, I'd run into the same problem as you mentioned in your 2nd bullet point.

Comment: If you override `action(for:forKey:)` (like in my example) to print the key (`event`), you'll discover what Core Animation asks for. I don't think it ever asks for `"frame"`, only `"bounds"` and `"position"`.

Comment: Note also that the view **will** receive a `layoutSubviews` message if its `bounds.size` changes, so you can use that to handle size changes reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I might have understood your questions wrong or misinterpreted the Apple documentation, but here are my thoughts on what to use to see frame changes:

1. You should not call view.layoutSubviews() directly. The LayoutSubviews method can be overridden by a subclass of UIView "only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly". - Copy from the Apple Documentation. I would therefore not use this method, since it doesn't apply to the view you want to change colors, but to the subviews of your view.
2. I think this is a very elegant way to use, since if you move the view the frame will be set to new values. However, when the frame changes size, the didSet will also be called and there might not be a movement of the frame. If your calculateColorFromFrame(frame) is an expensive method and the view can change size, this might cause some performance loss.
3. I think this is quite a cumbersome way to achieve the same as under point two. The only thing is that you now can use another class to observe changes in the view's frame and call the calculateColorFromFrame(frame) method.
4. viewDidLayoutSubviews() in the respective view controller is also a good way, but here this method is called when something in the main view of that view controller has changed and the view has to lay out its sub views again. This also means that this method can be called when your view hasn't moved or changed and the calculateColorFromFrame(frame) did not change. This might therefore again call this method a couple of times to often.

What I'm curious about is how you're effectively are going to calculate the odd and even pixel, since the frame position and size is based on points and a point can span more than one pixel.

I hope this answered your question.